# Чем отличаются директивы (new self) , (new self()) и self::?

Tags: php, ооп

Как я понимаю, это разное написание одного и того же, или что-то не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new self` и `new self()` — это одно и то же, создание экземпляра класса внутри себя, только во втором случае добавлены скобки для передачи аргументов (но сами аргументы отсутствуют).
Пример:

```php
public function instance()
{
    $instance = new self();
    $instance->data = 'Success';

    return $instance;
}
```

`self::` — это ключевое слово для обращения к статическим свойствам или методам внутри класса, либо к константам.
Пример:

```php
class Model
{
    const TIMEOUT = 60;
    public static $url = 'stackoverflow.com';

    public function test()
    {
        return [
            'timeout' => self::TIMEOUT,
            'url' => self::$url,
        ];
    }
}
```

P.S. По поводу комментария к вашему вопросу, для позднего статического связывания используется ключевое слово `static`, а не `self`.

[Подробная информация в документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)

Comment: Я разбираюсь в новом проекте, и тут как раз эти 3 варианта используются как возвращаемые значения из статической функции - return self::результат_запроса_в_бд , return (new self)->результат_запроса_в_бд и return (new self())->результат_запроса_в_бд

Comment: @СвиридовАлексей, мне сложно что-то вам ответить, т.к. я не знаю контекста и что вы подразумеваете под "результат_запроса_в_бд". Также можете для начала прочитать эту статью: [Ключевое слово static](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.static.php), возможно у вас пропадут все вопросы.

Comment: Да нет, тут ключевое что используется не как вызов статического метода, а в return . Получается начальный вопрос выглядит так - в чем отличие return self:: от return (new self)

Comment: @СвиридовАлексей, `return` не меняет сути, оно просто возвращает какой-то результат работы метода. `new self` используется для **создания** экземпляра класса, после чего вы можете обращаться через `->` к его свойствам и методам. А `self::` используется для обращения к статическим свойствам и методам **без создания** экземпляра класса.